# android.opengl.GLES11Ext.glGenFramebuffersOES throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, opengl-es, framebuffer

I'm attempting to use the static android.opengl.GLES11Ext in Honeycomb, but keep getting an exception when trying to generate a FBO. The code below works fine on multiple devices using the khronus package, but fails using android.opengl:

```
  private int createFrameBuffer(GL10 gl, int width, int height, int targetTextureId) {
  GL11ExtensionPack gl11ep = (GL11ExtensionPack) gl;
  int framebuffer;
  int[] framebuffers = new int[1];
  gl11ep.glGenFramebuffersOES(1, framebuffers, 0);
  framebuffer = framebuffers[0];
  gl11ep.glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);

  int stencilBuffer;
  int[] renderbuffers = new int[1];
  gl11ep.glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, renderbuffers, 0);
  stencilBuffer = renderbuffers[0];

  gl11ep.glBindRenderbufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, stencilBuffer);

  if(mContextSupportsStencilBuffer) {
    gl11ep.glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL11ExtensionPack.GL_STENCIL_INDEX8_OES, width, height);
    gl11ep.glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL11ExtensionPack.GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL11ExtensionPack.GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, stencilBuffer);         
  }
  else {
    gl11ep.glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL11ExtensionPack.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
    gl11ep.glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES,GL11ExtensionPack.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL11ExtensionPack.GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, stencilBuffer);
  }

  gl11ep.glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL11ExtensionPack.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES,GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, targetTextureId, 0);
  int status = gl11ep.glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES);
  if (status != GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Framebuffer is not complete: " + Integer.toHexString(status));
  }
  gl11ep.glBindFramebufferOES(GL11ExtensionPack.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, 0);
  return framebuffer;
}
```

The reason I want to use the android.opengl package is because it exposes the GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES extension which I need on some devices. Devices using the NVidea Tegra 2 chipset work fine with the above code. The Samsung 8.9" 4g device from AT&T however uses the Adreno 220 chip which doesn't support GL_STENCIL_INDEX8_OES. It does however support GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES using a FBO. I am relying on a proprietary rendering engine which only supports OpenGL ES 1.1 at this time. So going to 2.0 would not be easy or fast. How can I use the android.opengl package with extension GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES and a FBO in OpenGL ES 1.1? I've been googling for days, but haven't found a solution yet.

It would help a great deal if somebody has an implementation of the FrameBufferObjectActivity example from Goolge using the android.opengl package instead of khronos.

Comment: What is the exception you are receiving?

Comment: 02-03 15:39:54.815: E/TCLRenderer(20562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Framebuffer is not complete: 8cdd  This is because gl11ep.glCheckFramebufferStatusOES returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED